# Get total quantity and price from given dates

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hello guys I would like to ask how could I get the total quantity and total price of sales with this format of date. I was have this data in my database.

ID     Quantity    Price    Date

1       10          100          June 27,2016

2       12          120          June 28,2016

3      15          150          June 29,2016

I only getting one data with the first one row of 1 only.
I have this query.

```
$query= $this->db->select('SUM(total_price) as overall_price, SUM(quantity) as total_quantity')->from('sales')
        ->where('branch',$_SESSION['branch'])->where('date_sold >=',date('F d,Y',strtotime($from)))->where('date_sold <=',date('F d,Y',strtotime($to)))->get();
```

How could I also get all the records from specific range of date for example from June 27 to June 29 ? I only got 1 record

```
$query= $this->db->select('*')->from('sales')->where('branch',$_SESSION['branch'])->where('date_sold    >=',$from)->where('date_sold <=',$to)->get();
```

Comment: you need to `GROUP BY` your date field.

Comment: Don't forget [Raw](http://i.imgur.com/tXYTEId.jpg) sql when it gets complicated. Not that that image is complicated. But I know I'd be using raw or not the orm at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `BETWEEN`, something like: `$this->db->where("$something BETWEEN date('F d,Y',strtotime($from)) AND date('F d,Y',strtotime($to))");`